# Jest Mock React Hook Form setValue

Tags: reactjs, mocking, react-hook-form, setvalue

I'm trying to mock react-hook-form's setValue from another hook to verify it gets called.  See the code below - the output I am getting is that "setValue" is never called.  How can I mock setValue to see if it's called from another hook?

./useTest.js:

```js
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';


function useTest() {
    const {setValue} = useFormContext();
    setValue();
}

export default useTest;
```

./useTest.test.js:

```js
import useTest from './useTest';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';


describe('test', () => {
  const mockSetValue = jest.fn();
  jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-hook-form'),
    useFormContext: () => ({
      setValue: () => mockSetValue
    })
  }));

  it('test setValue mock', async () => {
     renderHook(() =>
      useTest()
    );

    expect(mockSetValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The test setup is almost correct for this use case, but there is a slight change needed here in how you can verify that it is getting called. You could use the `result` object returned by `renderHook` to verify that as follows

./useTest.test.js

```
import useTest from './useTest';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';


describe('test', () => {
  jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-hook-form'),
    useFormContext: () => ({
      setValue: jest.fn()
    })
  }));

  it('test setValue mock', async () => {
     const { result } = renderHook(() => useTest());

    expect(result.current.setValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

(Please also note the change on line 10 setting `setValue` directly to `jest.fn()`)

`testing-library`'s documentation on `renderHook`: https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#renderhook-result